# Implement and consume trait for another trait

Tags: rust

I have a trait that I would like to be able to use as an iterator and I would like the iterator implementation to make use of the custom trait implementation. Is something like the below possible in rust, where two trait implementations are dependent on each other, or is a different architecture recommended?

```rust
trait Generator {
    fn generate(&self) -> String;

    fn generate_many(&self, count: usize) -> Vec<String> {
        self.take(count).collect()
    }
}

impl Iterator for dyn Generator {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(self.generate())
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Attempt with supertrait

```
trait Generator: Iterator {
    type Item = String;

    fn generate(&self) -> String;

    fn generate_many(&self, count: usize) -> Vec<String> {
        self.take(count).collect()
    }

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(self.generate())
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to declare `Iterator` as a supertrait of `Generator`, and implement `generate()` based on `Iterator::next()`, or maybe drop the `generate()` method altogether.

Comment: The code in your edit doesn't compile because it doesn't implement the rest of @SvenMarnach 's comment, implementing `generate()` in terms of `Iterator::next()`. It's [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77b8d315a345ba32a624df8c2dc3fec5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you'd write a blanket implementation of `Iterator` for anything that implements `Generator`, such as:

```
impl<T: Generator> Iterator for T {
    // ...
}
```

But Rust won't accept that because you can't provide blanket implementations of traits you didn't define in your own crate - that would violate the [orphan rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#implementing-a-trait-on-a-type).

However, nothing stops you from *wrapping* any `Generator` in your own generic type that implements `Iterator`:

```
struct Wrapped<G: Generator>(G);

impl<G: Generator> Iterator for Wrapped<G> {
   // ...
}
```

This doesn't violate the orphan rule because the blanket implementation only applies to variations of the `Wrapped` type that we've defined locally, and leaves `T` itself untouched. It is zero-overhead because `Wrapped<G>` just stores `G` directly, whatever `G` is, introducing no allocation or indirection.

Finally, you don't even need to implement the above struct, you can leave the wrapping to the [`iter::from_fn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html) helper provided by the standard library:

```
fn iter<G>(g: &G) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + '_
where
    G: Generator + ?Sized,
{
    std::iter::from_fn(move || Some(g.generate()))
}
```

Then you can *use* `iter()` to implement `generate_many()`:

```
fn generate_many(&self, count: usize) -> Vec<String> {
    iter(self).take(count).collect()
}
```

Runnable code in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fec65ddacb8bc85883e6e63fe5275998).